# @Url.Content not pointing to correct path in a new MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having trouble figuring out why when I create a new MVC 3 application the jQuery intellisence is not working until I alter the script tag in my _Layout page. According to a tutorial I watched, as long as I placed the vsdoc file in my scripts folder, I should have jQuery intellisense but that is not the case, at least thats not happening for me. After creating a new project, here is what the script tag looks like in my _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have included the vsdoc file in my Scripts folder but I do not have jQuery intellisense. If I do a view sorce on the page here is what I see:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It doesn't look as if the path is correctly resolved.
So I then delete this tag and replace it by dragging and dropping the file to the page and end up with this:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now I get jQuery intellisense. So why do I have to make these changes befeore I get intellisense? Is this something that others have experienced or am I possibly doing something wrong? It seems like the @Url.Content functionality is broke and leads me to wonder if maybe I will have problems with it for other uses like placing images on a form.

Comment: It's not `Url.Content()` which is broken; it's IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, your vsdoc.js script cannot just exist in the scripts folder.  It has to be referenced in every view that will use it.

You should reference it like this:

```
@if (false) {
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

*Note: Check the version of the file that you reference is correct.*

The if statement will prevent the browser from actually downloading the file.

Comment: Hi Dangerous, I get jQuery intellisense to work just fine leaving it in the scripts folder as long as I remove the script tag placed in the _Layout page when the project is created (the one using (@Url.Content) and add the reference to the .js file dragging it onto the page from the scripts folder which then has a different markup as shown in my original post. If I leave both script tags on the page and run it, then look at Viw Source, I get these markups:

Comment: Looks like the the edit I made here didn't take. Here is the markup from the script tag using @Url.Content:   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
Here is the other markup:   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                        It looks like the first markup does not resolve correctly but I'm not sure.